# Downvote increased my reputation

Tags: support, reputation, voting, down-votes

Today, I had the feeling that I had to urgently downvote an answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33879497/246260).  I might have been factually wrong there, but that is not the matter.

`<Naivety mode on>`

I am not very active on SO recently.  Is there some algorithm that finds bad answers and honours downvotes with +1 reputation?  Because exactly this is what happened.

`<Naivety mode off>`

Seriously, I was expecting a -1 appearing in my reputation changes, but the exact opposite happened.  Any reason why?

Comment: Maybe an edit was approved at the same time? Maybe two downvoted answers were removed? The drop-down notifies you of the rep changes since you last clicked on it. Sometimes it gets wiggly (maybe you left the tab inactive for so long?) and it forget to notify you. A lot of cases are possible. Now, done with the speculation, let's go to your rep tab. (update: It seems you have an edit approval from 10:24; ring any bells?)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You downvoted the answer, but you also [submitted a suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12771582) that was approved. +2 from the edit - 1 from the vote = +1. Mystery solved. :)

Comment: This question should go on Math.SE. ;)

Comment: @PatrickHofman Stack Overflow is a graduated site, so obviously MathOverflow is the right choice here. :)

Comment: Ouch.  I think my last accepted suggested edit was a loooong time ago.